# In iOS8 can access to the keychain be limited only by auth by fingerprint

Tags: ios, keychain, ios8, touch-id

I need to securely store/retrieve items on iOS keychain.

From Apple KeyChainServicesReference doc (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html) I retrieve keychain items using  SecItemCopyMatching call. The latter pops up a system prompt for authenticating against local keychain that allows using fingerprint or, alternatively, a 4-digit phone passcode.

While I consider auth with fingerprint secure, it's that 4 digit PIN option that downgrades my current security. So, my question is: is there a way to query keychain with just fingerprint option (no passcode option and if fingerprint auth fails, it just fails, no fallbacks to 4 digit passcode)

I have looked into LocalAuthentication and although the latter provides the exact flow that I need, LA doesn't give me access to the keychain and thus LA is of no use to me

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Apple stated that the fingerprint auth is no more secure than a 5 digit PIN. Best bet is for the user to have chosen to use a more secure passcode. There is added security in the attempt limit.

Answer (score 1):

In LAContext.h:

```
/// Fallback button title.
/// @discussion Allows fallback button title customization. A default title "Enter      Password" is used when
///             this property is left nil. If set to empty string, the button will be hidden.
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *localizedFallbackTitle;
```

This code removes the button and user can either use their finger or cancel:

```
LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];
context.localizedFallbackTitle = @"";
[context evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics ...
```

Comment: Is this ok to implement in an Appstore app? Do Apple REQUIRE a fallback option?

Comment: This works, but it is not KeyChain and is not as secure. See this post for the difference between KeyChain and LocalAuthentication: https://www.cigital.com/blog/integrating-touch-id-into-ios-applications/

Answer (score 1):

You're right, in iOS 8 you have no option to store an item in Keychain and make it accessible only after successful Touch ID authentication. The `kSecAccessControlUserPresence` access control flag added in iOS 8 makes an item accessible after either Touch ID or Passcode authentication.

But this can now be done in iOS 9. Two Touch ID-related flags, `kSecAccessControlTouchIDAny` and `kSecAccessControlTouchIDCurrentSet`, [have been added](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS90APIDiffs/Objective-C/Security.html).

So, all you need to do is use either of these two flags when creating access control object for Keychain item (with `SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags` function), and assign that object to `kSecAttrAccessControl` attribute when adding the item with `SecItemAdd` function.

There is [an example from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KeychainTouchID/Listings/KeychainTouchID_AAPLKeychainTestsViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014530-KeychainTouchID_AAPLKeychainTestsViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_8) that demonstrates this; see `addTouchIDItemAsync` method.

Also see [this post](https://nabla-c0d3.github.io/blog/2015/06/16/ios9-security-privacy/) for an overview of other security-related changes in iOS 9.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't dived into iOS 8 keychain yet, but remember that the 4-digit passcode is set by a user. Apple recommends that when users turn on TouchID, they also turn on a more complex password, saying "Since security is only as secure as its weakest point, you can choose to increase the security of a 4-digit passcode by using a complex alphanumeric passcode." http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5949

So, **the user still has the option of using something more complex than a 4-digit passcode**. You just can't force them to do it. If you really want to force them, it sounds like you have to abandon the convenience of Touch ID.

Comment: A more secure can be forced under MDM.

Comment: Richard. As you mentioned, I can't force users to upgrade their passcode strength. And I believe that there is a different perception what needs to be more secure here, app-related keychain data vs being able to unlock phone.